# How to avoid inconsistency with syntax of OpenLink Virtuoso SQL in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset, virtuoso

In Apache Superset if OpenLink Virtuoso database is used (ODBC driver + Alchemy dialect), the following error is displayed for **any** SQL query:
[image]

That's because Apache Superset automatically adds `LIMIT` clause to any SQL statement from SQL Lab, but Virtuoso SQL does not support `LIMIT` clause in SQL statements. (Virtuoso uses [`TOP`](https://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/topselectoption/).)

For example, such initial SQL statement in SQL Lab

```sql
SELECT TOP 3 count(*) FROM DBA.VALUE_FACT
```

is received by Virtuoso ODBC driver as follows:

```sql
SQL = [SELECT TOP 3 count(*) FROM DBA.VALUE_FACT
LIMIT 101][length = 51]
```

**Is there a way to fix that problem by configuration changes in Superset?**

It may be curious to know that SPARQL queries (which start with keyword `SPARQL`) are working fairly well in SQL Lab.

Answer (score 0):

There are others who want to [disable that `LIMIT` clause in Superset](https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/18483). It doesn't appear possible, yet (but add your name to the list!).

I would suggest you also [request that Virtuoso](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/) add support for `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` in its SQL dialect, as it already supports `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` in SPARQL ... which would explain why the SPASQL (SPARQL-in-SQL) queries are working in Superset.